# How can the results of a pipeline be captured in a batch var without temp file?

Tags: variables, batch-file, redirect, pipeline

Trying to get the number of disks in a system using diskpart without using a temp file. This works on the command line:

```
echo list disk | diskpart | find /C "Disk"
```

but I can't figure out how to redirect the result into a batch var. Of course the number printed by the above pipeline is higher due to labels, but they are constant (divide result by 3 for actual number of disks).

Any ideas?

I've tried:

```
set /A disks=<echo list disk...
set /A disks<echo list disk...
set /A disks= (echo list disk ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `FOR F` for capture the output of a program.

```
set "cmd=echo list disk | diskpart | find /C "Disk""
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%A in (`!cmd!`) do (
    set var=%%A
)
echo !var!
```

Comment: Aside from the misplaced quote in the set, this was perfect! I'm relatively new here, so how does one accept this answer, or am I thinking of some other similar form?

Comment: The quotes are perfectly placed, that is the extended syntax of the `set` command, to avoid trailing whitespaces and work with special characters

Comment: @motechman To accept an answer, click on the hook under the number

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a batch file using `WMIC` like this:

```
@echo off
wmic logicaldisk get caption,providername,drivetype,volumename > ListDisk.txt
Start "" ListDisk.txt
pause
```

And if you want to echo the fixed drive like that :

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=3" ^|find /i ":"') do (Set FixedDrive=%%i)
echo %FixedDrive%
pause
```

Comment: This script needs to run under Windows PE, so I don't think the WMIc API is available on that platform. I tried using it for another issue and wmic was not found.